# How to parse a datetime string without a year in Joda Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to convert a string into a Joda Time `DateTime` value. The string representation contains day, month, hours and minutes, but no year.

How can I do it?

I tried something like `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM HH:mm").parseDateTime("26.03 02:50")`, but got following exception:

```
org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException: Cannot parse "26.03 02:50": Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (Europe/Moscow)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:471)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:440)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:411)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:882)
```

Comment: `DateTime` should contains date, and any date contains `year`. It is impossible to have abstact date without year. So, I think answer: there is no way.

Comment: @Andremoniy There is always a workaround. I'm pretty sure that I'm not the first person, who has to deal with year-less date representations.

Comment: do you mean that it should take the current year?

Comment: @SergeyPauk I need a `DateTime` object with or without a year. In the next step, I determine the year and will set the year of that object (there is already a routine, which calculates the correct year).

Comment: why don't you resolve the year in advance and add it to your date string?

Comment: @SergeyPauk Good point. I'll think about it.

Comment: @SergeyPauk Actually, it wasn't possible to know the year in advance. Imagine those date times represent date times of a movie performance (or a sports game) and the system receives only tickets with dates in future. Let's assume today is `21.03.2015 09:10` and you get two tickets - one with date `21.03. 09:09` and another one with date `21.03. 09:11`. `21.03. 09:09` gets converted to `21.03.2016 09:09` and `21.03. 09:11` to `21.03.2015 09:11`. Why? By definition, we receive only future dates. Therefore the year depends on whether day-month-time is before or after the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close to it... for example use the parseLocalDateTime function:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM HH:mm").parseLocalDateTime("26.03 02:50");
```

But be aware that this solution ignores any probably given time-zone information.